# Loading sql text file into variable and submitting insert/update query via pymysql produces warnings - safe to ignore?

Tags: python, mysql, warnings, pymysql

I have some stored procedures that are stored in a .sql file.  I want to use pymysql to add these to the DB.  So, I am loading the file into a variable, like this:

```
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        sql = file.read()
```

Then I am using pymysql to submit that, like this:

```
    connection = pymysql.connect(...)

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql)

    connection.close()
```

This seems to work great, but I get warnings that concern me.  They look like this:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:322: Warning: (139, 'Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.')
self._do_get_result()
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:322: Warning: (1246, "Converting column '' from VARCHAR to TEXT")
self._do_get_result()
```

My question is:  are these safe to ignore?

Update:

I figured out the first warning (the one about Row size too large):  The sql text file that generated that warning was a View creation, not an SP creation, and the amount of fields in the view did exceed the row size, so mystery solved there.  I'm still trying to figure out what exactly is causing that second warning.

Update 2:

I figured out the second warning.  The sql text file that generated that one was an SP creation, and there was a variable declared in there as DECLARE v_sql VARCHAR(32000).  I changed that to VARCHAR(2000) and the warning went away.  So, it looks like having variables greater than a certain size will generate that warning.

Comment: You should post your table structure

Comment: @Hack5 - there is no table structure.  These .sql files just create store procedures.  So, they are just CREATE PROCEDURE statements.

Comment: well I don't have very much experience with SQL but as one of the warnings refers to a column, I assume you must have a table (otherwise where did the column come from?)

Comment: @Hack5 - exactly.  my guess is that pymysql is internally using some kind of table structure to execute the cursor or something?  no clue.  that's why I'm posting this.

Comment: oh if its not a noob mistake I know nothing, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For the first warning I posted, the issue was: The sql text file that generated that warning was a View creation, not an SP creation, and the amount of fields in the view did exceed the row size

For the second warning I posted, the issue was:  The sql text file that generated that one was an SP creation, and there was a variable declared in there as DECLARE v_sql VARCHAR(32000). I changed that to VARCHAR(2000) and the warning went away. So, it looks like having variables greater than a certain size will generate that warning.